# Find input box of a specific type as well as its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9z4j/12/).

I can use the following to find an input box with a specific value:

```
$('input[value="'+findtext+'"]');
```

but is it possible to find an input box of a specific type as well? This one won't work in the example:

```
$('input[type="checkbox" value="'+findtext+'"]');
```

HTML:

```
<button class="check">AAA</button>

<input type="radio" value="AAA">This
<input type="checkbox" value="BBB">This
```

Script:

```
$('.check').click(function(){
   var findtext = $(this).text();console.log(findtext);
   $('input[type="checkbox" value="'+findtext+'"]').attr('checked', true);

});
```

Comment: Why don't you use `id` for that element and then find it?

Comment: be careful on special chars ("[]) in the findtext string

Comment: @user1389596 Would you please tell me what you mean by that?

Comment: If the findtext string contains a " char, it will break the syntax.  For example $('input[type="checkbox"][value="extra"char"]').attr('checked', true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this will do the trick:  `$('input[value="BBB"][type=checkbox]')`

[**Online Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9z4j/13/)

```
$('.check').click(function(){
   var findtext = $(this).text();console.log(findtext);
   $('input[value="' + findtext  + '"][type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true); 
});
```

This is subject of [multiple attribute selectors with JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) in case you want to read more about it.